# How to get the required version of the Composer Plugin API?

Tags: composer-php

It is necessary to do the following:

```
composer self-update
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:*"
```

But after executing the composer self-update, an error pops up:

```
The "hirak/prestissimo" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("~1.0.0-alpha10") that does not match your Composer installation ("1.1.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
```

My current version of Composer is 1.4.2
For the same reason, the following commands do not work:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:*"
```

An error pops up:

```
The "hirak/prestissimo" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("~1.0.0-alpha10") that does not match your Composer installation ("1.1.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
```

How to get the required version of the Composer Plugin API?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to update `hirak/prestissimo`:

```
composer global update hirak/prestissimo --no-plugins
```